# Yobit API POST request (R)

Tags: r, api, httr

I try to request to [yobit API](https://yobit.net/en/api/) wthin R. 
To get access to some of the methods you need to complete authentication:

**Each Trade API request should pass authentication.
Authentication is fulfilled by sending the following HTTP-titles:**

**Key - API-key, example: FAF816D16FFDFBD1D46EEF5D5B10D8A2**

**Sign - digital signature, POST-parameters (?param0=val0 & ...& nonce=1) signed by secret key through HMAC-SHA512**

**Parameter nonce (1 minimum to 2147483646 maximum) in succeeding request should exceed that in the previous one. To null nonce it is necessary to generate new key.**

My code :

```
nonce=1   

API_KEY = "0B02AD5AF57854184D68D3D1D4D980F9"
API_SECRET = "89b20f882220b5dc6feeb33253c25ba3"
Body=paste('method=getInfo&nonce=',nonce, sep="")
sign = hmac(API_SECRET, Body, algo="sha512")
title=add_headers('Content-type'='application/x-www-form-urlencoded', Key = API_KEY, Sign = sign)
rep=POST('https://yobit.net/tapi', body=Body, headers=title,  encode='form')
nonce=nonce+1
```

Response from server:

```
"{\"success\":0,\"error\":\"invalid key, sign, method or nonce\"}"
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

this i have done in node js And its working.

```
const crypto = require("crypto");
var apikey = 'apikey';
var secret = 'secret';

var signature = "method=getInfo&nonce="+ nonce;

console.log(signature);

var hmacsignature = crypto.createHmac('sha512', secret).update( signature ).digest('hex');

var headers = { 
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Key': apikey,
    'Sign': hmacsignature
};

var options = {
    url: 'https://yobit.net/tapi',
    method: 'POST',
    body: signature,
    headers: headers
}

console.log(options);

request1(options, function (error, response, body) {
    res.send(body);
});
```

Comment: OP asked for help in the R language, so while your answer is appreciated, it does not help people looking for an answer to OP's question (i.e. how to solve this in R).